# Openshift phpmyadmin error connection (http/https)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift

I, m trying to connect to my phpmyadmin in order to manage my mysql db in openshift PaaS Cloud.
The connection page shows up but when i put my usr/pswd I get :

connection to blablablabla.rhcloud.com:80. : ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

When I change the url to http i get a #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.

I'm kind of lost as I'm new to all of this..

IF I try to change the port in url to 8080 or 443 the server doesnt answer..

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the phpmyadmin cartridge and then re-installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your url similar to `https://www.yourdomain.com:2083/` (mind the 's' at the end of http)

Is your website SSL enabled?

If you are unsure the best option would be to contact your host provider to get things sorted.

Comment: yes it is https://  xxxxxx
the openshift platform should work on https mode cause it enables it by default..
Will try to report the bug to them..